# Google App Script says Action Not Allowed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've encountered a problem while trying to figure out a way to automate the sharing of individual files using a script that runs inside a spreadsheet. Essentially what I am trying to do is add editors to individual spreadsheets inside a folder. These editors are not part of a group (just others GMail accounts), and should not have folder level access for adding/removing files.

The code I have is:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('File Access').addItem('Grant Access', 'addUser').addToUI();
}

function addUser() {
  var ui = SpreasheetApp.getUI();
  var response = ui.prompt('Grant Access', 'Enter the email address to grant access for:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButtion() != ui.Button.OK) {
    return;  // Ignore Cancel button
  }
  var emailAddress = response.getResponseText();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.addEditor(emailAddress);
    ui.alert('Granted access to: ' + file.getName());
  }
}
```

When I test it out on my own drive, where I own the spreadsheet, the App Script, the folder which anyone can view, the files in the folder which I want to affect, it works fine. 
However, if a colleague, who has edit access to the spreadsheet where that function lives and edit access to the files going to be affected, attempts to run it they get the `Action not allowed` error upon execution, even after granting authorization.

The weird part is, if I allow anyone to edit the folder, it works flawlessly. However, it is not feasible to manually add my colleagues for edit access to that folder, and certainly not secure if I let anyone edit that folder.

I thought that since I am intending to modify the individual files inside the folder, that folder level edit permission would not be needed. My colleagues can already go in and grant access to the spreadsheets from inside them, via the normal Share menu, however it is tedious to do this for all files inside the folder.

I would prefer a solution that can use the Menu UI inside of Google Sheets. From what I've read, deploying as a Web App may get around this apparent permissions issue, however I'd like to stay away from that if possible.

Comment: By the sounds of it when one of your colleagues runs the script they are trying to add permissions to a folder which they do not have rights to add permissions to. Just going on the fact that when you allow all it works as intended. Upvoting for a well written question.

Comment: I haven't tested this, so I'm not sure about it, but here are some thoughts.  Even though the other user has edit access to the Sheet, when the user does something to trigger code to run, the code may be running under the authority of the user, and not "as you."  You could try publishing the script as a Web App to run "As Me."  I don't know if that will do anything, but you could try it.  If that doesn't work, you could have a separate, stand alone Apps Script file that is published as a Web App, and runs as you.  Then call that Web App from your Sheet script with UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)

Comment: Do they have edit access to all the files in that folder?

Comment: @TheMaster THANK YOU! My test environment was not set up the same as the production environment which was causing the issue. I guess I overlooked that detail when setting up all the files